# How to achieve the variable globally?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a few code lines like this,

```
public void rt_changed(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
{
    //Label l = sender as Label;
    foreach (DataListItem li in datalist.Items)
    { 

      Label l = li.FindControl("nl") as Label;

    }
    Label3.Text = l.ToString(); // l values is not getting
 }
```

Here the variable l is null. I know it's happening because the declaration of l has been made inside the scope of the foreach. I don't know how to call the variable with value in globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move the declaration of the `l` variable outside of the loop to make it available. You can declare (tell what it is) in a different place than where you assign it a value.

```
public void rt_changed(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
{
  // Declare l, also give it a default value, in the case that datalist is empty.
  Label l = null;
  foreach (DataListItem li in datalist.Items)
  { 
    l = li.FindControl("nl") as Label;
  }
  Label3.Text = l.ToString(); // l values is not getting
}
```

Please note that `l` will only get assigned to the last value in the `datalist` collection, which probably isn't exactly what you want.

Comment: But in this case, can i get value of l to label3 ?

Comment: Yes you will. Your variable will be available anywhere in the event handler.

Comment: Here am getting System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label in the place of label3.

Comment: @Anders Abel. You are right, as you said am only getting last value in the datalist. How can i change my code to get as my wish ?

Comment: @gkrishy That's another question, please post it as a new one. Comments on Stack Overflow are not well suited for follow up questions.

Comment: @AndersAbel Thanks for your suggestion and answer. Please follow the link to view my new question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556499/why-the-datalist-showing-only-last-value-with-my-code].

Comment: To be nit picking `l` will be assigned to each the values one at a time, but when exiting the loop `l` contains the last assigned value.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable in the outer scope:

```
 public void rt_changed(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
 {
     Label l = null;
     foreach (DataListItem li in datalist.Items)
     { 
          l = li.FindControl("nl") as Label;
     }          
     Label3.Text = (l == null ? string.Empty : l.Text); 
 }
```

Also make sure to test whether the variable is not null before using it (to avoid null pointer exception); in the example I did this using the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Tip 1: name your variables with a more meaningful name ('l' doesn't say much).

Tip 2: use `Text` property to get label text instead of `ToString()`

Comment: Still am getting the same thing. System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label is passing in the place of label value.

Comment: Use Text property instead of ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Its simple,

```
public void rt_changed(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Label l = sender as Label;
        foreach (DataListItem li in datalist.Items)
        { 

          Label3.Text = (li.FindControl("nl") as Label).Text;

        }

     }
```

Comment: I don't want like this. Because, i need to call my label value further lines in this scope. As per you answer, i won't get label values outside of the scope.

Comment: Even though Label3 is a control. You can access Label3 where ever in that page, right?