# Why the Datalist showing only last value with my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public void rt_changed(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
{
  // Declare l, also give it a default value, in the case that datalist is empty.
   Label l = null;
   foreach (DataListItem li in datalist.Items)
   { 
      l = li.FindControl("nl") as Label;
   }
   Label3.Text = l.Text; // l values is not getting
 }
```

In this, am getting only last value from my Datalist to Label3. Based on my click am not getting the values in label. 
What should I change/do in this code ?

Comment: @Anders Abel Have you seen my question ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing the last record is that you are not retaining the value of your label in your loop. Better use a `StringBuilder`.

```
public void rt_changed(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // Declare l, also give it a default value, in the case that datalist is empty.
    Label l = null;
    foreach (DataListItem li in datalist.Items)
    {
        l = li.FindControl("nl") as Label;
        sb.AppendLine(l.Text);
    }
    Label3.Text = sb.ToString(); // l values is not getting
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Still am facing the same issue.

Comment: @gkrishy, so you are still seeing the last item only ?

Comment: No. Here am facing the different thing. Sorry for my last comment. The thing is 'merging'. Here all the string from the datalist got merge.

Comment: @gkrishy, use `sb.AppendLine(l.Text)` to have new line in between your contents

Comment: Now am getting all the string with space in between. But what i need is, i want the separate values depends on the click. For eg: am having three names on datalist(He, She, They) with image button(image got bind). On each click of image i want respective name in Label. Hope i didn't confuse you much.

Comment: @gkrishy, you lost me in the last comment. What you are exactly trying to do, your original question doesn't have the details that your last comment is asking for.

Comment: Sorry for the confusions. I already have mentioned on my question right ? ** Based on my click am not getting the values in label.** So based on my selected image, i need to show the respective name.

Comment: If you have the index of the row you clicked on, why are you looping through every label?

Comment: @entropic for achieving datalist item values(Label). I struggled to declare the datalist item value, so I used for loop to declare values. Sorry if am wrong in my way. Just guide me datalistitem declaration without foreach. I need to call the label within datalist.

Comment: Without seeing the html/asp.net code there's no way for me to know what you are passing to the function.  Usually, clicking a link within a datalist would give you some index as to what link you clicked.  From there, you would take that link and use `dataList.Items[{index}].FindControl(....` to get only the label you want.  Not all of them.